# Backend Checkboxes working – but not visual?

Tags: admin, admin-menu, dashboard

first…sorry for my bad English.

Since a few months I have a problem with the checkboxes in the wp backend.
They are working, but you can´t see that they are activated.
(see enclosed picture as an example for a plugin, but the problem is in all checkboxes in the wp backend)

[image: example for checkboxes]

This is very confusing, because I can´t remember all my settings in wordpress and the plugins. (yes, I´am to old!)

I discussed this in the german wp-forum. But we can´t find a solution.

What I have tried:

- changed the browser
- deactivate all plugins
- Repeat to install the new wp version (manually)
- Change the Theme
- deactivate all plugins in the new theme

No change!

Others have find a solution with the “admin bar”, but its still not working for me. (I activated it, I deactivated it – no change)

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?
Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards
Pat

Comment: wow, that's weird! if it's for every checkbox I wonder if there's something like a bad jQuery command that's acting on all checkboxes. Does anything appear in view-source? like badly formed HTML? What version of Wordpress? The only thing I can think of that would definitely diagnose is to make a new clearn Wordpress install and install theme and plugin one by one until you see the same behaviour

Comment: Hello! Can you use the built in image uploader for your image so it displays in your questiion? Linking offsite to an image makes it very unlikely that people will click on it, and your Q is broken if that site changes or goes down. At the moment your Q doesn't explain the problem using words and sentences, so it's unreadable to a large number of people

Comment: @Tom
Hope the edit post with the image is better?

Comment: @mozboz
Yes, every checkboxes in Wordpress backend / normal settings and in all checkboxes of the plugins. I use the newest version of Wordpress. I installed wordpress manually again via FTP. Only let the wp-content and the wp-config.php untouched. But nothing happens. I´am still helpless.

Comment: Problem is solved! :-) It was code in the .htaccess that causes the problems with the checkboxes. I delete it, everything works fine. Thank you for the help. Can I mark this question as solved? And.....can I post the code (new question?) to find out what line causes the error?

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was related to my web servers Content Security Policy.  Needed to add "data:" as a possible source

```
default-src data: 'self' *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com;
```

If you are using more specific CSPs like font-src: and img-src: you may also need to allow it within those as well.